# incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by caller

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsarray

Hi everyone i am running my code through the analyzer tool in the IDE where i am getting an indication  in the dealloc and saying  "incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by caller" i am creating an NSArray and releasing properly my code sample is below

myClass.h

```
{                                                         
NSArray *arrayOfChapters;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrayOfChapters; 

@end
```

myClass.m:

```
-(void)parseAndLoadChaptersAndPages{
self.arrayOfChapters = chapterLoader.arrayOfChapters;
}
-(void)dealloc{
    [self.arrayOfChapters release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

can any one tell me the  problem why it is giving me the warning.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you did not call `[super dealloc]` in `dealloc`. Also try `[arrayOfChapters release]` instead of `[self.arrayOfChapters release]`.

Comment: Since you using properties, you should let the setter release the object. Do self.arrayOfChapters = nil instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can either release the ivar directly (`[arrayOfChapters release]`), or you can set the property to nil (`self.arrayOfChapters = nil`) and the setter method will release the ivar for you.

The object owns the ivar `arrayOfChapters`, but not necessarily the return value of the `arrayOfChapters` method that you are calling using the property syntax. It's a bit confusing because both the ivar and the method have exactly the same name. In this case the `arrayOfChapters` method returns the ivar, so it's not a problem. However the analyser thinks the method could theoretically return a different object, in which case you would be over-releasing that object.